# PHP if statement returns same value

Tags: php, variables

My code is always returning true when I'm comparing these variables.
What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
    $postuser = (integer)bp_activity_user_id();  //echos 1int(0)
    $posteduser = (integer)bp_activity_comment_user_id();  //echos 3int(0)

    if ( $postuser === $posteduser) {
       echo 'true';
    } else {
       echo 'false'; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: I don't understand 'echos 3int(0)'. Why would that code echo anything, and why would it show two values like that?

Comment: What is `1int(0)`? it's either `1` or `int(0)`. What is your value?

Comment: try: `if ((int)$postuser === (int)$posteduser) { }`

Comment: Try var_dump($postuser,$posteduser,$postuser===$posteduser);

Comment: I solved this with the docs... http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/buddypress/nav.html?_functions/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the function that RETURNs the value, not outputs it.

From docs I found for whatever this is,

> bp_activity_user_id()   X-Ref
>   Output the activity user ID.
>
> bp_get_activity_user_id()   X-Ref
>   Return the activity user ID.
>
> return: int The activity user ID.

The function you are using echoes the variable, NOT returns it and therefore you can't set a variable with that function. Same for the this function.

> bp_activity_comment_user_id()   X-Ref
>   Output the ID of the author of the activity comment currently being displayed.
>
> bp_get_activity_comment_user_id()   X-Ref
>   Return the ID of the author of the activity comment currently being displayed.
>
> return: int|bool $user_id The user_id of the author of the displayed

To use in an assignment, the function has to return a value. That's why your values are always (int)0: the functions you are using have no return value. So, it returns null which is cast to 0.

```
<?php
  $postuser = bp_get_activity_user_id();  

  $posteduser = bp_get_activity_comment_user_id(); 

//no need to cast: these functions return integers


     if ( $postuser === $posteduser) {
        echo 'true';
        } else {
        echo 'False';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use intval and == i think it should work and evaluate it fine

```
<?php     

      $postuser = intval(bp_activity_user_id());  //echos 1int(0)

      $posteduser = intval(bp_activity_comment_user_id());  //echos 3int(0)

      if ( $postuser == $posteduser) {
          echo 'true';
       } else {
            echo 'False'; 
       }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your prbolems are probably the wrong typecasts:

Change `(integer)` to `(int)`

```
$postuser = (int)bp_activity_user_id();  //echos 1int(0)
$posteduser = (int)bp_activity_comment_user_id();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php